# Calculating sum of multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data from one data provider in very thin demographic units: Adults_18_21,Adults_22_24,Adults_25_27, etc.

Then in the original data frame that is built like this:

```
DemoDF = pd.DataFrame({'City':['NYC','Chicago','Nash'],'Adults_18_21':    [100,50,75],'Adults_22_24':[200,300,400],'Adults_25_27':[300,100,200]})
```

From another data provider, we get larger buckets of advertising data, Adults_18_27.

```
AdvertisingDF = pd.DataFrame({'City':     ['NYC','Chicago','Nash'],'Adults_18_27':[1,2,3]})
```

To multiply ad rates by demographic, I am currently creating a dictionary of tuples:

```
Compare_Buckets = {
'Adults_18_27':('Adults_18_21','Adults_22_24','Adults_25_27')
}
```

Then creating new columns based on the tuples:

```
for key in Compare_Buckets.keys():
        DemoDF[key] = 0
        for value in Compare_Buckets[key]:
            DemoDF[key] += DemoDF[value]
```

I can then take the new resulting column and join it with the AdvertisingDF based on city and do any further functions I need. There are 40+ keys in the dictionary so I thought the for loop would work best. Is there a better way or a more memory efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the whole [`filter`ing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas.DataFrame.filter) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) using `pandas`' builtins:

```
for group, individuals in Compare_Buckets.items():
    DemoDF[group] = DemoDF.filter(items=individuals).sum(axis=0)
```